# How to expand a dataframe by assigning to each value in column 3 values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
 index   day   
 0       21  
 1       2
 2       7
```

and to each day I want to assign 3 values: 0,1,2 in the end the dataframe should look like this:

```
 index   day   value
 0       21      0
 1       21      1
 2       21      2
 3       2       0
 4       2       1
 5       2       2
 6       7       0
 7       7       1 
 8       7       2
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could introduce a column containing `(0, 1, 2)`-tuples and then `explode` the dataframe on that column:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'day': [21, 2, 7]})
df['value'] = [(0, 1, 2)] * len(df)
df = df.explode('value')
df.index = range(len(df))

print(df)
```

```
    day value
0   21  0
1   21  1
2   21  2
3   2   0
4   2   1
5   2   2
6   7   0
7   7   1
8   7   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
N = 3

df = df.assign(value=[range(N) for _ in range(len(df))]).explode("value")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   index  day value
0      0   21     0
0      0   21     1
0      0   21     2
1      1    2     0
1      1    2     1
1      1    2     2
2      2    7     0
2      2    7     1
2      2    7     2
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex) option:

```
df = (
    df.reindex(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index, [0, 1, 2]]),
               level=0)
        .droplevel(0)
        .rename_axis(index='value')
        .reset_index()
)
```

`df`:

```
   value  day
0      0   21
1      1   21
2      2   21
3      0    2
4      1    2
5      2    2
6      0    7
7      1    7
8      2    7
```